# Parâmetro name em URLconfs do Django

Tags: python, django

Na URLconf abaixo:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

Qual a função do parâmetro `name`? É possível explicar com um exemplo prático?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O parâmetro `name` serve para referenciar a URL. Por exemplo, se quiser apontar um link para o index no template, você utilizaria o seguinte código:

```
<a href="{% url 'index' %}">Acessar o index</a>
```

Na **view**, você pode pegar a URL através do `reverse`. Nesse exemplo é feito um redirecionamento:

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.urls import reverse

def redirecionar_para_o_index(request):
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index'))
```

Na [documentação](https://docs.djangoproject.com/pt-br/1.11/topics/http/urls/) você pode ver mais detalhes.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta. Só acrescentar que a importação "from django.urls import reverse" só funciona no Django 1.10. No Django 1.9, a importação correta é "from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse".